# get values before certain date in sql

Tags: sql, date, multirow

i have one question about get multi rows before the date getting infection:

```
patientID   Appt_reason dateofProcedure
1                        1/2/2016
1                        1/3/2016
1             infectoin  1/4/2016
2                        3/1/2016
2                        3/3/2016
3                        3/4/2016
3             infectoin  3/5/2016
3                        3/6/2016
3                        3/7/2016
5                        2/2/2016
5             infectoin  2/3/2016
5                        2/4/2016
```

I need to get rows like this

```
patientID   Appt_reason dateofProcedure
1                       1/2/2016
1                       1/3/2016
1          infectoin    1/4/2016
3                       3/4/2016
3          infectoin    3/5/2016
5                       2/2/2016
5          infectoin    2/3/2016
```

anybody know the answer? thanks

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 22):

```
SELECT
    patientID,
    Appt_reason,
    dateOfProcedure
FROM
    tableName
WHERE
    dateOfProcedure < '2016-04-03'
```

Note I'm using ISO-8601 format which is unambiguous and supported by all modern database systems.

Note that it's using the `<` (less-than) operator instead of `<=` (less-than-or-equal to) because in SQL a date literal value can represent date*time* values, so `'2016-02-01' >= '2016-02-01 01:00'` is actually `false`, because `'2016-02-01'` has a hidden time component equal to midnight, and 1am is after midnight.

Comment: I think dateOfProcedure < multiple time, not certain time.

Comment: In SQL (the query language) a `DATE` can **not** be a "datetime". There are two distinct data types in SQL: `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` the latter including a time. The only DBMS that I am aware of that includes a time even with a plain `DATE` is Oracle.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name that's why I put emphasis on the "can" word, because if the column is `datetime` (instead of `date`) then a `'yyyy-MM-dd'` literal or parameterised value would be compared as a `datetime` instead of a `date`. The OP didn't say what the type of the `dateOfProcedure` column was.